# Most precise and efficient way to write data in Fortran

Tags: arrays, file-io, fortran, gfortran, file-writing

Suppose I have some program that at each iteration `i` outputs some data, `a,b,c`.

**What is the best way** to write this data to a file, with regards to both speed and precision? What are the Fortran standard methods/ best practices for writing this data to file?

My current considerations are:

- Writing all data to an array and then writing this array to file.
- Writing line-by-line to unformatted binary file.
- Writing line-by-line to text file.

I understand that writing to an array then to file will be faster, but what about the precision in each case? What about the situation where I do not know the value of *i* and so cannot initially define an array size?

Comment: *Writing line-by-line to unformatted binary file.* There are no lines in an unformatted file. But yes binary files will be the best. But you should state some criteria for selection, otherwise it is really opinion based.

Comment: What do you mean by precision? Rounding precision loss during writing and subsequent reading? This does not happen during unformatted (binary) I/O.

Comment: Do you need one single output file for all time-steps?

Comment: I don't really get you write to an array. You mean filling an array during the whole computation and writing it at the end at once? That sounds pretty problematic. Doable, but will waste memory and will need reallocations from time to time.

Comment: Also, what about external libraries like NetCDF or HDF5? Do you consider them?

Comment: Writing a single array to binary will be best unless the data is so large that you run into memory issues.  In any case, nix the last option. Do not use text if you care about precision.

Comment: @VladimirF So no precision is lost during binary I/O?In what case would one use HDF5?

Comment: If you do not need to transfer your written data - feel free to use binary format - in this case you will write exactly the same numbers which you have in memory. In case if you need some portable data format - you may start considering some libraries. Probably writing huge (orders of several GB) files may be a challenge as well - there you may also look into some additional I/O means

Comment: I think we need more specifics about your case. As worded, the question is too general.